# How to enable syntax-highlighting in ckeditor5? (like ckeditor4 + codemirror plugin)

Tags: codemirror, ckeditor5

I'm using ckeditor on a backend web application for different editing needs.
One of the most used features is editing xml or json files that act as configuration files for webservices or other apps.
This was done with ckeditor 4 or previous with the codemirror plugin, enabling ckeditor as a simple web code-editor.

We are planning to migrate to ckeditor5 but I cannot find a way to achieve the same results (using ckeditor5 to edit xml or json with syntax-highliting).

Any ideas are welcome.

Regards